# Get array key by value - multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to get/find array key by some of array's values.

I tried `array_search` but this doesn't help with multidimensional arrays as I hoped.

For example I have this kind of array and I need to get all array keys where `personal_code = 12345678910`. In this example I should get `array(0,1)` because in first and second array are the personal_code `12345678910`.

How could I get those keys?

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [id] => 32155
    [personal_code] => 12345678910
    [cadaster] => 12345:321:1234
    [purpose] => Purpose 1
    [address] => Blah blah 1
    [area] => 600m2
  )

  [1] => Array
  (
    [id] => 14131
    [personal_code] => 12345678910
    [cadaster] => 12345:123:4321
    [purpose] => Purpose 2
    [address] => Blah blah 3
    [area] => 1200m2
  )

  [2] => Array
  (
    [id] => 32303
    [personal_code] => 54321678910
    [cadaster] => 12345:123:1234
    [purpose] => Purpose 3
    [address] => Blah blah 2
    [area] => 1800m2
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a simple foreach to get those keys. Example:

```
$find = '12345678910';
$keys = array();
foreach($your_array as $key => $values) { // loop your array
    // now values will hold each array batch inside that parent array
    if($values['personal_code'] == $find) { // so it if matches
        $keys[] = $key; // then put it inside
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($keys);
```

[Sample Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nmucC8)

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($yourArr as $arr)
{
  if($arr['personal_code']==12345678910)
  {
    $newArr []=$arr;
  }
}
print_r($newArr);
```